# SQL cast char to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following t-sql:

```
set @sql = 'select id, query from '+@tablename+' where '+GETUTCDATE()+'> cast(ExpirationDate as datetime)'
execute sp_executesql @sql
```

I am getting this error:

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

How can i properly convert this?

Comment: One big question that nobody has yet asked....why oh why are you storing datetime information in a varchar column? Use the proper datatype instead of wrestling with nonSARGable queries all the time because the first thing you have to do is CAST/CONVERT to the datatype it should be in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @sql = 
    'SELECT id, query 
    FROM '+@tablename+' 
    WHERE CAST('''+CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS VARCHAR(30))+''' AS DATETIME) 
          > CAST(ExpirationDate AS datetime)'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put the function call *inside* the query string:

```
set @sql = 'select id, query from '+@tablename+' where GETUTCDATE() > cast(ExpirationDate as datetime)';
```

I don't see any advantage to putting it in before you call `sp_executesql`.

Comment: Tried that, but i have a need to use dynamic sql

Comment: That is still using dynamic sql. There is no requirement that you have jump through extra hoops to get the value of GETUTCDATE. Let sql server work you instead of fighting it.